# How to get the MAC address of network interface that running on windows with multiple interfaces?

Tags: node.js, windows, mac-address

How to get the MAC address of network interface that running on windows with multiple interfaces using Nodejs?

ipconfig /all and getmac can't get a exact result.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [network](https://www.npmjs.com/package/network) package from npm.

**Install:**

```
npm install network
```

**Use:**

```
const network = require('network');

network.get_active_interface(function(err, obj) {
  console.log(obj.mac_address);
})
```

Comment: @ MikaS Thanks for your replying.The package network works perfectly but package getmac only return mached MAC adress first in default and maybe not a running interface.